# how do i use local video url path in grails <g:link> tag?

Tags: jquery, grails, lightbox

I am using jquery lightbox and using the local video url using:

`<g:link
 url="/resources/corporate/videos/A_Installing_Metrofax_Printer.mov">Watch Demo Video</g:link>`

When I try to run this
 source, the link is opening a blank popup. How can I make it play using
 `<g:link>`?

Comment: If resources folder is inside web-app you can use `g.resource` with attributes dir and file.

Comment: when i am using g.resource, it showing download popup window to save video. video player popup is not showing.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Grails. You need to learn how to embed video on a page. Research.

Comment: If i can use direct youtube url with lightbox, it working fine. But when i am using local url, it is not working. Embed will creating the video link on the same page, but i want the video link in popup.

Comment: The embed code for an YouTube video is not the same as a local video. Look for html5 video.